# Constructing a submanifold transversal to a given vector field

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

Suppose you have a pseudo-Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$ and a vector field $X$ defined on $M$ (which is everywhere non-zero). Is it easy to find a submanifold $\Sigma \subset M$ such that $\Sigma$ is transversal to $X$? (that is, for each $p \in \Sigma$, $X(p)\notin T_{p}\Sigma$).

I suspect the preimage theorem is a sensible bet: if we could find a collection of vector fields $Y_{1},\ldots,Y_{n-1}$, which are pointwise linearly independent of $X$, and that, say, 
$$f(p)=g(Y_{1}(p),X(p))^{2}+\ldots+g(Y_{n-1}(p),X(p))^{2}$$
has $0$ as a regular value, then the manifold $\Sigma=f^{-1}(0)$ would be a submanifold of dimension $n-1$ with $X(p) \notin T_{p}\Sigma$. Does something like that sound right?

Answer (score 5):

It is easy to construct *locally* such a manifold. A well known theorem tells you that around a point you can find coordiantes $x_1,...,x_n$ such that in this chart $X= {\partial \over \partial x_n}$, and the submanifold $x_n=0$ does the job.

In general it is *impossible* to construct a *compact* connected submanifold with this property. Consider the Hopf vector field $X$ on the 3-sphere $S^3$, wich is everywhere tangent to the fibers of the Hopf fibration $f: S^3\to S^2$. A compact submanifold $\Sigma$ transverse to $X$ would be a covering of $S^2$, hence $f$ would induce a diffeomorphism  $\Sigma \to S^2$. The existence of such a manifold would imply that $S^3$ is diffeomorphic to $S^2\times S^1$ and this is not the case.

Comment: Ah! The reason I'm looking for such a manifold is that I'm trying to prove the theorem you state (the notes I'm reading assert the existence of such a submanifold in order to prove it). Does it have a name?

Comment: @DanielLittlewood I recall seeing a proof in Warner's book *Introduction to Differentiable Manifolds* that I don't think asserted the existence of such a submanifold.

Comment: The theorem stated in the first paragraph here is often called the Flowbox Theorem. (Oh, and no metric is needed. Just a differentiable structure.)

Comment: Then the proof is much easier. By linear algebra you can find a system of coordinates such that $X(0)= e_n$ the last vector of your base. Then at the origin, $X$ is transverse to $x_n=0$, and by continuity, it is transverse to this plane in a neighborhood of $0$.